# object is not updating in recursively called function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get data through recursive function, but my response object is not updating when the recursive function is called;

```
    function checkData(id) {
    var response = {
        new_id: '',
        status: false
    }

    var order = somefunction(id);

    var isOriginal = order.isOriginal
    var enddate = order.enddate
    var new_id = order.originalId

    // first check
    if (enddate == '' && isOriginal) {
        response.new_id = new_id;
        response.status = true;
    }

    //second check
    if (!isOriginal) {
        if (new_id) {
            checkData(new_id); // recursive call
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

if the second check condition meets, it loads the data but when the response is consoled it shows the initial data which initialized earlier. the response variable is not updating with a recursive call. However, it updates if the first check passed.

Comment: Every time you call your recursive function, `response` is re-initialized. Either put the object in the upper scope, or pass it as argument to the function.

Comment: or return the result of your recusive call, currently it's recursively working but never returning anything

Comment: @FredStark, where to exactly return it, tried to return response in the first check but got the same

Comment: `return checkData(new_id)`

Comment: then it will recurse until there is an original response and each call will return that response unwinding all the function calls and finally being returned from the first call. Otherwise it never returns from recusive calls

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong, I guess then it will just look for 2 times, not for the third recursive call?

Comment: There's no count, it will continue to recurse until `isOriginal` is true

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments @Fred Stark, successfully solved by retuning the recursive call,

```
function checkData(id) {
var response = {
    new_id: '',
    status: false
}

var order = somefunction(id);

var isOriginal = order.isOriginal
var enddate = order.enddate
var new_id = order.originalId

// first check
if (enddate == '' && isOriginal) {
    response.new_id = new_id;
    response.status = true;
}

//second check
if (!isOriginal) {
    if (new_id) {
        return checkData(new_id); // recursive call ---> called return here
    }
}
return response;
}
```